# Configuration files not generated in /etc/cassandra after upgrading to Cassandra 4.0.5

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

Cassandra 3.11.16 upgrade to 4.0.5,all seems good,but under /etc/cassandra,nothing generated by cassandra installer except triggers folder

When I installed c* 4.0.5 directly on a brand new machine,it generated conf file such as cassandra.yaml,cassandra-env.sh correctly. The os version is ubuntu 18.04,cassandra installed by apt.After I copied conf file to /etc/cassandra, c* works well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide the exact steps you followed and provide as many details as you can about the problem you are seeing now.

Comment: below is how I upgrade c*:
1.echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 40x main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
2. wget -q -O - https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
3. apt update
4. apt install cassandra

Comment: Normally,c* installer generates the configuration files in the /etc/cassandra folder,but not this time.

Comment: the c* original version is 3.11.13

Comment: I tried it again and found that this problem occurs when you install the same version of c*,not when you upgrade from an older version

Comment: sometimes it will install the files, but call them rpmnew or something similar to that, can you check to see if any of those were generated?

Comment: The problem was solved. Install the same version c* as the installed,the installer will not generata conf files in the /etc/cassandra/.

Comment: Install a different version of the c* ,then the installer will ask you whether to replace the conf files.If you select no, the installer will generate *dpkg-dist-new  file

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information in your post but I suspect you missed a step somewhere along the way and something is misconfigured. For example, if you have not configured the correct package source (still pointing to 3.11 distribution) then nothing will get installed/upgraded on your machine.

In fact, I have reason to believe that you are still using the old repositories. Back in August 2022, we [announced on the Cassandra user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/gjc4p989c6tx16jdc7jxon4c87s2qjv2) that the package repositories were moved ([CASSANDRA-17748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17748)):

> [WARNING] Debian and RedHat package repositories have moved! Debian
> `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list` and RedHat
> `/etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo` files must be updated to the new
> repository URLs. For Debian it is now [debian.cassandra.apache.org](https://debian.cassandra.apache.org).
> For RedHat it is now [redhat.cassandra.apache.org/40x/](https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/40x/).

We also announced the changes in the August ([Changelog #18](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-Changelog-18-August-2022.html)) and September ([Changelog #19](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-Changelog-19-September-2022.html)) blog posts on the Apache Cassandra website.

The reason I suspect you are still using the old repo is that the cluster was previously running with C* 3.11.13. Had you been pointing at the new C* 3.11 source, running `apt install cassandra` would have installed the latest version which is currently C* 3.11.14 (at the time of writing).

Had you configured the new C* 4.0 source, Cassandra 4.0.7 would have been installed -- not C* 4.0.5. This is because the old repos have not been updated so they do not have the latest versions.

You need to configure the nodes to use the new repositories. For example, the C* 3.11 series (`311x`):

```
$ echo "deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

For the C* 4.0 series (`40x`):

```
$ echo "deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 40x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

Make sure you remove the old repository from the sources list. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Erick! I post my steps  in the comment.And I have configured the new C* 4.0 source,but it point to 4.0.5. 
I check the apache source files, it did point to 4.0.5

Comment: Package: cassandra
Version: 4.0.5
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Eric Evans <eevans@apache.org>
Installed-Size: 57387
Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless | java8-runtime | openjdk-11-jre-headless | java11-runtime, adduser, python3 (>= 3.6), procps

Comment: ^^ I've taken it from the apache source packages file

Comment: For future reference, you should post details in the **Body** section instead of the comments area to make it easy for others to help you.  Cheers!